# What is the atmospheric transmission factor in the energy equation of Lidar?

Tags: optics, energy, visible-light

I have the following equation for calculating the intensity of the received laser beam in a lidar sensor.

$P_r = \dfrac{P_t. N_s. N_a. r. D_r^2}{4.R^2}$

where $P_r$ is received power, $P_t$ is transmitted power, $N_s$ is system transmission factor, $N_a$ is atmospheric transmission factor, $D_r$ aperture diameter of receiver, $R$ distance traveled by the beam, and r is the reflectivity of the hit object.

From, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2211379718324963, 
System or Geometric transmission factor $N_s$ is given by:

$N_s = -10[log(\dfrac{A_r.A_d}{L^2. \lambda^2}) + 2log(\dfrac{4}{pi})]$

and from Kim model, $N_a$ is given by,

$N_a(\lambda, L) = exp[- \gamma_T(\lambda)L]$

$\gamma_T(\lambda) = \dfrac{3.91}{V}(\dfrac{\lambda}{550nm})^{-q}$

$q = 0$ as the range of Lidar is 100m. However, Both the above equations yield intensity in decibels. Could someone help me solving the energy equation for,

$P_t = 8 W, \lambda = 905 nm, r = 0.8, D_r = 105mm, R = 50m.$

How can I calculate transmission factors to substitute in the above energy equation?

Comment: Practically, you wouldn't calculate it. You'd need to design for a range of values.1.0 for clear air. Some lower value you'd probably want to measure for the worst case scenario you want to be able to handle (heavy smoke or fog in the air).

Comment: Hello, I am designing lidar in a simulation environment and would like to know the total transmittance given the weather condition, wavelength, and distance. What would be the better way to do it?